# "Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix" in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.ararbtuerkat_db.aratuerk.db" >

<!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <intent-filter/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:label="@string/title_activity_login" >
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".RegisterActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_register" />
            activity/>
        application/>
</manifest>
```

I'm editing the `AndroidManifest.xml` when I got that error in the bold text. How can I fix it? I added the complete code on request.

Comment: Please share the complete contents of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Does your Android Manifest contains these lines of code at the beginning.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

> Update 1:

There is bug in your manifest file :

Change this :

```
<activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <intent-filter/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            android:allowBackup="true"

            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"

            android:label="@string/app_name"

            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

to

```
<activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"  />
```

> Update 2 :

Change

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET />
```

to

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

> Also kindly change all the activity and application closing tags to

```
 </activity> and </application> respectively.
```

Comment: Well know that is fixed but I get "Tag start not closed at : android:name=".LoginActivity"

Answer (score 0):

Your `Manifest` file looks wrong, unless if something went wrong when you were copying it here. But below is how I think you manifest should look. You can change the "`your-package-name-here`" with your actual package name.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="your-package-name-here" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />

            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

            <activity
                android:label="@string/title_activity_login" >
            </activity>

            <activity
                android:name=".RegisterActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_register" />
            </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Give it a try and let me know if this helps.

Comment: Nope didnt do anything.

Comment: What is the name of the `Activity` class with the label `title_activity_login`? Also, could you please explain what the error is?